# How do I observe variable in Model class use SwiftData?

Tags: swift, swift-data

I try to observe 3 `Component.isValid` variables use `_tracking()` function to calculate `isAvailable` in `Model RGB` class.
but, It not works for observation.

Anyone have solution or advice for that? thx.

```
import SwiftData

@Model class Component {
    var id: String
    var range = 0...255
    var value: Int {
        didSet {
            self.isValid = self.range.contains(value)
        }
    }
    var isValid = false
    
    init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, value: Int = 0) {
        self.id = id
        self.value = value
        self.isValid = self.range.contains(value)
    }
}

@Model class RGB {
    var id: String
    var R: Component
    var G: Component
    var B: Component
    var isAvailable = false
    
    init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, 
         R: Component = Component(),
         G: Component = Component(),
         B: Component = Component()) {
        self.id = id
        self.R = R
        self.G = G
        self.B = B
        _tracking()
    }
    
    private func _tracking() {
        withObservationTracking({ [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            self.isAvailable = self.R.isValid && self.G.isValid && self.G.isValid
        }, onChange: { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            print("tracking: \(self.isAvailable)")
            self._tracking()
        })
    }
}

let rgb = RGB()
rgb.R.value = 10
rgb.G.value = 20
rgb.B.value = 30
// if _tracking function works that isAvailable should be true.
rgb.R.value = 300
// if _tracking function works that isAvailable should be false.
```

Comment: Why not a computed property?

Comment: @loremipsum thanks, I want to add some condition for isAvailable variable  in _tracking() function in the future.

Comment: Why is Component even a model, I fail to see what the purpose is with it? Maybe you can solve this by re-designing your data models. To me it looks like R, G and B should be declared Int and isValid should be a function or computed property.